# Specifying package data in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I use `setuptools`. In `setup.cfg`, I can define

```
[options.package_data]
myModule =
    '*.csv'
```

to make sure that data will be installed for my users.

Can I achive the same with `pyproject.toml` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if I understand your concern, you are using `setuptools` as a building and distributing system and you want to move some configs from `setup.[py,cfg]` namely `package_data` to `pyproject.toml`, if so you have to use an other tool to build and distribute your package e.g `poetry` as stated in @Romibuzi's answer because it's not possible unless the setuptools' team plan a new major release to include a full support of `pyproject.toml` and then no need for extra/standalone config `setup.cfg` file.

some references:

- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#basic-use
- https://discuss.python.org/t/where-to-get-started-with-pyproject-toml/4906/4

## Update

as per [v61.0.0](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/history.html#v61-0-0), setuptools brings a partial support (still in beta version) for this feature.

refer to @LudvigH's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73062301/12368419). (thank you btw)

Comment: so is it possible or not?

Comment: As this is the chosen answer, please update it based on LudvigH answer. Setuptools now works.

Comment: I think now if you use the pyproject.toml and build using the build pypi package, all should work. `pip install build`, then `python -m build --wheel`

Answer (score 35):

Starting in setuptools version 61.0.0 there is beta support for this feature. See the documentation https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/datafiles.html

The syntax is

```
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
myModule = ["*.csv"]
```

*Update 2024-01-12:* This is no longer in beta. A handful of different mechanisms can enable for data inclusion. One mechanism is to ask for automatic discovery based on git. It should suffice to set the setuptools version and enable the `-scm` plugin. Now all files tracked by git will be considered data files. The relevant section is...

```ini
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=60",
    "setuptools-scm>=8.0"]
```

I produced a complete example and posted on github. https://github.com/el-hult/mypkg

Read the full documentation for more options.

Comment: If you have *both* `setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml`, adding the above in `pyproject.toml` seems not to work.

Comment: You may need: `find . -name '*.egg-info' -exec rm -r {} + && rm -Rf build`

Comment: Note: if your project is namespaced, the syntax is `"path.to.myModule" = [...]` i.e. you need quotes around the key

Comment: Although this answer is sufficient for the question posed here, it's not the best on the page. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76435649/567059 for a more complete example, and one that matches the recommended package structure to use when creating packages.

Answer (score 4):

As of now, if you are using `pyproject.toml` and `setuptool` you do not need to do anything. Just add some extra files in the same directory as your Python code.

But note that **it will only add them if they are checked into source control, and you are using `setuptools-scm`** (the example tells you to so you probably are).

For example this is my `pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "foo"
authors = [
    {name = "...", email = "..."},
]
description = "..."
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.9"
dependencies = [
    "pydantic",
    "jinja2"
]
version = "1.0.1"

[project.scripts]
foo = "foo:main"
```

And I have these files:

```
.
├── pyproject.toml
├── pyrightconfig.json
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── foo
        ├── command.py
        ├── index.html
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── render.py
        └── triage.py
```

And when I run `python3 -m build` it does add `index.html` to the wheels.

Also `setup.py` is just for backwards compatibility. You don't actually need it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a project dir structure like

```
project_root_directory
├── pyproject.toml 
└── src
    └── mypkg
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── data1.rst
        ├── data2.rst
        ├── data1.txt
        └── data2.txt
```

simply add the following to your pyproject.toml

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
mypkg = ["*.txt", "*.rst"]
```

More info can be found in the docs @ https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: Indeed. That is also what my answer indicate, and you provide the same link as I do.

Comment: Ah not sure how i missed that!  wanted to add a quick example anyway for anyone searching for a quick solution :)

Comment: This answer is better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/73062301/567059 because it showed the need for `[tool.setuptools.packages.find]`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other existing answers, one can also simply use a `MANIFEST.in` file.

See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/

Comment: This is a good complementary point. It often serves a different purpose than `package_data`, but can still be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hatchling, per the [docs](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/), you can also do this via:

```
[tool.hatch.build]
include = [
  "myModule/**/*.csv",
  "**/*.py",  
]
exclude = [
  "tests/**",
]
```