# How do I specify "extra" / bracket dependencies in a pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, dependencies, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I'm working on a project that specifies its dependencies using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/) and a [pyproject.toml](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0621/) file to manage dependencies. The documentation for one of the libraries I need [suggests](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/main/README.rst) pip-installing with an "extra" option to one of the dependencies, like this:

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery[opentelemetry]
```

How should I reflect this requirement in the `pyproject.toml` file?  Currently, there are a few lines like this:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.7.10"
apache-beam = "2.31.0"
dynaconf = "3.1.4"
google-cloud-bigquery = "2.20.0"
```

Changing the last line to

```
google-cloud-bigquery[opentelemetry] = ">=2.20.0"
```

yields

```
Invalid TOML file /home/jupyter/vertex-monitoring/pyproject.toml: Unexpected character: 'o' at line 17 col 22
```

Other variants that don't seem to be parsed properly:

```
google-cloud-bigquery["opentelemetry"] = "2.20.0"
```

There are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775346/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-pip-install) StackOverflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647590/can-i-specify-package-data-in-pyproject-toml) which look related, as well as [several](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) [different](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0621/) [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0660/), but my searches are complicated because I'm not sure whether these are "options" or "extras" or something else.

Comment: try quoting the left-side string too

Comment: @t17 Ah!  `"google-cloud-bigquery[opentelemetry]" = "2.20.0"` appears to parse at least.  Thank you!   Although it still tells me `google-cloud-bigquery[opentelemetry] (>=2.0.0) which doesn't match any versions`, so maybe not working right either

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can add it by `poetry add "google-cloud-bigquery[opentelemetry]"`. This will result in:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
google-cloud-bigquery = {extras = ["opentelemetry"], version = "^2.34.2"}
```

Comment: ahah - this looks like what's wanted if it works!

Comment: Confirmed in Poetry v1.3.2: `poetry add "aiohttp[speedups]"` resulted in pyproject.toml entry: `aiohttp = {extras = ["speedups"], version = "^3.8.3"}` and successfully installed dependencies.

Answer (score -3):

Though the syntax looks a little strange, TOML supports quoting keys to escape special characters as of some version "**Less restrictive bare keys**"
https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/pull/283

```
"google-cloud-bigquery[opentelemetry]"
```

This syntax may work for you!

```toml
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.7.10"
apache-beam = "2.31.0"
dynaconf = "3.1.4"
"google-cloud-bigquery[opentelemetry]" = ">=2.20.0"
```

TOML may expect `^` `>=`, though the syntax isn't clear from the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#dependencies-and-dev-dependencies)

Comment: When I tried this, it seemed to try to install a version of a package with the literal name "google-cloud-bigquery[opentelemetry]", not package "google-cloud-bigquery" with option "opentelemetry"

Comment: alas, I've seen something similar, but never used Poetry - glad the other Answer works!