# Add dependencies to [tool.poetry.extras]

Tags: command-line-interface, python-poetry

I need to add dependencies to extra dependencies of **my package**, not packages that I depend on.
But everywhere it's described how to add package to my dependencies with their extras (e.g. [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386332/how-do-i-specify-extra-bracket-dependencies-in-a-pyproject-toml))

My `pyproject.toml` contents:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my_project"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8"
PyYAML = {version = "^6.0", optional = true}
matplotlib = {version = "^3.5.1", optional = true}

[tool.poetry.extras]
my_extras = ["PyYAML"]
```

Previously I just manually edited `pyproject.toml`, but now these bundles of extras are propagated to `poetry.lock`, so if I do it just in `pyproject.toml` I get warning from `poetry` that my lock file and pyproject file are not synchronised. (Of course I can edit them simultaneously, but it's a dirty way)

What is the command to add `matplotlib` to `my_extras`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no command to add a dependency to an extra group. You have to manual edit the `pyproject.toml` and run `poetry lock --no-update` afterwards.