# Adding folder with data with `pyproject.toml`

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I would like to package some legacy code to a `hello` *Python* package containing only one module (`hello.py`) file in the top-level directory alongside with some data in a folder called `my_data` without changing the folder structure:

```
hello/
|-hello.py
|-pyproject.toml
|-my_data/
  |-my_data.csv
```

Packaging the *Python* source code with the following `pyproject.toml` file is surprisingly simple (without any prior knowledge on packaging), but running `pip install . -vvv` fails to copy the data:

```
[project]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1"

[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = ['hello']

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
hello = ['my_data/*']
```

The content of `hello.py` could be minimal:

```
def hello:
    print('Hello, world!')
```

I tried multiple variants of this `pyproject.toml` file according to the documentation on http://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/datafiles.html as well as a related question on [Specifying package data in pyproject.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647590/specifying-package-data-in-pyproject-toml), but none of them would result in copying of the `my_data/` folder directly into the `site-packages` folder (which is intended, but probably bad practice).
I also found documentation suggesting to use a `MANIFEST.in`>

```
graft my_data
```

but also this doesn't result in the data to be installed alongside the code.

Comment: Is setuptools a must, or would, e.g., hatch be acceptable?

Comment: Damn, I actually just put hello.py in the same folder as pyproject.toml. You'd need to adjust paths accordingly, but I don't have the time to fix it just now

Comment: I would need a solution using `setuptools` for reasons of compatibility.

Comment: Edit your question to show where the `pyproject.toml` is located in the source directory tree. Do you really not have any `__init__.py` files? Where does the `rippl_AI` come from? -- Always try to provide a full, standalone [mre].

Comment: With a `pyproject.toml` it seems the `__init__.py` is no longer necessary; I placed an empty one, which does neither harm nor help. I edited the code snippets to include your suggestions.

Comment: Every single Python importable package must have an `__init__.py` (it might work without, but that is just a coincidence). -- Your project directory structure is incorrect. `pyproject.toml` should be outside of the `hello` directory. I recommend you follow this tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Your example function is invalid (missing parameter list)

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just forgot to include the `[build-system]` table in your `pyproject.toml`.

## Setuptools

For setuptools, put this in your `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[project]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project.scripts]
hello_script = "hello:main"

[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = ['hello']

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
hello = ['my_data/*']
```

## Hatch

Assuming you'd want to use hatch, you can do this.

Put this in your `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[project]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1"

[build-system]
requires = ['hatchling']
build-backend = 'hatchling.build'

[project.scripts]
hello_script = "hello:main"

[tool.hatch.build]
include = ['hello.py', 'my_data/*.csv']  # see https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/#patterns
```

## Reproduce

Follow these steps to reproduce my results.

### Files

First you set up the project by adding all necessary files.

This is the `hello.py` script I used:

```py
from csv import reader
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    csv_path = Path(__file__).parent / "my_data/my_data.csv"
    with csv_path.open() as csv_file:
        csv_data = reader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_data:
            print(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the `my_data.csv` file I saved to `my_data/`:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

After adding the `pyproject.toml` to the project root, you should have a directory structure like this:

```
hello/
  ├── hello.py
  ├── my_data/
  │   └── my_data.csv
  └── pyproject.toml
```

### Install

After setting up your project, you can just `pip install .` it.

### Test

Now call `hello_script` to test whether the data was installed alongside the code. If you do this in the project root, it will fail, because then it imports the `hello.py` in the project root and not the installed version.

This is the output I get after leaving the directory, and deleting `my_data/` (to ensure it's not loading that):

```
$ hello_script
['a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'f']
```

Please note, that not bundling everything into a folder is kinda messy, and usually not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for you solution, which I can confirm to work when using `hatch`. In the long run I should maybe switch to it, but for the moment I would require a solution with `setuptools`.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Fair enough! I'll see if I can get it to work with setuptools tomorrow

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki seems that it was a quite simple fix actually. I've added a section on setuptools

Answer (score 0):

The [`package-data`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-package-data) configuration of `setuptools` can be used when you have a `package`. But instead you seem to have a a single file-module. In other words `package-data` is incompatible with the directory structure that you have.

I suggest rearranging the files like the following:

```
hello/
|-pyproject.toml
|-hello/
  |-__init__.py  # <----- previously named `hello.py`
  |-my_data.csv
```

```
# pyproject.toml diff
...

  [tool.setuptools]
- py-modules = ['hello']
+ packages = ['hello']

  [tool.setuptools.package-data]
- hello = ['my_data/*']
+ "" = ['*.csv']  # <--- "" (empty string) means "all packages".
```